# Paypal Express Checkout instead of default checkout

Tags: opencart, paypal

I am looking for a way of adding the *PayPal express checkout* button to products in OpenCart store. I am trying to achieve the ability to purchase via PayPal instantly while bypassing the default checkout process in OpenCart. Similar to this http://www.lakeland-furniture.co.uk/eames-eiffel-dar-lounge-side-dining-chair.html

I have searched but I cant find anything similar. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, read our HELP pages and focus on what [questions You should avoid to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). This question is basically considered as Off Topic here.

Comment: Hi shadyyx, I agree part of the question could be off topic, and for that I apologise, but the other half (way of adding) could be considered on topic, as I believe this would be a code editing solution, I just don't know what and I am trying to reach out to the developer community for a solution. Thanks

Comment: I have modified Your question's title and description a little so that it does not appear to be an OT anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this ability with PEC checkout extension (http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=191) but it is not free, but works good and code from the famous developer in open cart.

Or also you can realized it yourself using PayPal API